# What does an import from ".." mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, module

While working on a TypeScript project in VSCode, I imported an interface from another file, and allowed VSCode to insert the `import` statement for me.  However, I was surprised to find the import statement looked like this:

```
import { IOAdapter } from '..';
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
import { IOAdapter } from '../adapters/IOAdapter.ts';
```

Is this `..` syntax new?  How does it work?

I'm using TypeScript 3.4.1.

---

Update: @Paleo's solution is correct, see my comment on his answer for the source of my confusion.

Comment: Module specifiers are largely environment-dependent. Do you use a bundler of some kind? (And does vscode know that?)

Answer (score 4):

When a directory is imported, TypeScript imports by default the file `index.ts`.

Your import is equivalent to: `../index`.

*Warning: I have never found anything official to confirm this behavior (in particular, there is nothing in the [TS specification](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#1131-module-names)). It works like that. But I'm unsure if it is a good practice to use this feature.*

Comment: Do you have a documentation link for that? It's not in [the modules documentation](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). I mean, it's kind of what I'd assume if someone told me it was a valid module specifier, but...

Comment: No. I searched several times to confirm that. I never found anything official. :( But it works like that. I'm not sure if it is a good practice to use this feature.

Comment: Ah, you're right!  I forgot that I had imported and re-exported this interface in my app's main `index.ts` file, so VSCode chose to import the interface from this file instead of the original source.

Comment: This is the default for the intellij IDE 2020.1 when automatically detecting imports.